# Using list comprehension, tuples and itertools.groupby

Tags: python

This has been giving me some trouble for a while, maybe I've got tunneled vision. Given a list of integers, generate a new list where every group of adjacent duplicates has been turned into a tuple.

For example, given the list: `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]`

The generated list contains: `[1, 2, (3, 3), 4, (5, 5, 5), 6]`

I'd like to achieve this using list comprehension.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]

it = itertools.groupby(numbers)
numbers = [tuple(group) if len(tuple(group)) > 1 else key for key, group in it]
```

The result I'm expecting:

`[1, 2, (3, 3), 4, (5, 5, 5), 6]`

The result I'm getting:

`[1, 2, (), 4, (), 6]`

The inserted tuples are empty, apparently - but at the same time they're not, since they would have had to have had more than one element in them to get inserted in the first place. What's going on? I'm new to python, and even after exhausting all the keywords I can think of I still haven't been able to find a similar question online. I'm sure it's something simple and I just can't see it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the group variable is an iterator that only can be iterated once. It appears empty after exhausting. You need to store the intermediate group temporarily. One way to go is using nested generators/comprehesions as itzmeontv suggested, or to use a mapping function:

```
def make_group(group):
  group = tuple(group)
  if len(group) == 1:
    return group[0]
  return group

numbers = [make_group(group) for key, group in itertools.group_by(numbers)]
```

Comment: Thank you Tamas! I've accepted your answer as the one that solved my problem because you provided an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do `list comprehension`

```
>>>l = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
>>>[k[0] if len(k) == 1 else tuple(k) for k in [list(j) for i,j in itertools.groupby(l)]]
[1, 2, (3, 3), 4, (5, 5, 5), 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this one

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
[(i,)*a.count(i) if a.count(i)>1 else i for i in set(a)]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, (3, 3), 4, (5, 5, 5), 6]
```

Comment: I don't know if OP wants them in order, but your answers won't return the numbers in order in most cases (just for small numbers), (besides having a non-optimal time complexity).